# X and Y are i.i.d with Uniform distribution in $[0,1]$. Let $M=XY$. What is the distribution of $X|M=1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

X and Y are i.i.d with Uniform distribution in $[0,1]$. Let $M=XY$. What is the distribution of $X|M=1$ and $X|M=0$?

so,  $M=XY$ and $U=Y$

$g_{1}(x,y)=xy$ and $g_{2}(x,y)=y$
$h_{1}=m/u$ and $h_{2}=u$

$J = 1/u$

So I will have: $f_{M,U}(m,u)=1/u$. Am I right?

To calculate $X|M=1$ I have to notice that $X = 1/y$

What I have to do is simply calculate the distribution o $1/Y$?

I got really confused here.

Any help?

Many thanks

Comment: Note that $f_{X|M}(x|m) = \frac{f_{X,M}(x,m)}{f_M(m)}$ and so it will likely benefit you more to compute the density of $(X,M)$, rather than $(M,Y)$. You could use $g_1(x,y) = x$ and $g_2(x,y) = xy$.

Comment: If $M=1$, doesn't that mean that $X=Y=1$ ?

Comment: If $X=1/3$, then $Y$ would need to equal 3.  But $Y\sim U[0,1]$.

Comment: @JimB Yes, that does simplify, I didn't notice the special case $M=1$ is of interest.

Comment: @JimB X|M=1 will take the distribution of X, right? Or X|M=1 doesnt exist.

Comment: You need to think it through more.  Neither of those possibilities you mention work.  If given $M=1$, then $X$ must take on just the single value 1.  So $Pr(X=1|M=1)=1$ and zero for all other values of $X|M=1$.

Comment: @Michael I found $f_{m}(m) = 0$. Is it weird? As I found $f_{u,m}=1/u$, to find $f_{m}$ I integrate $f(x,m)$ in u $\in[0,1]$

Comment: @JimB exactly. But even when I set $m \in (0,1)$  I can find the joint distribution but the marginal of M I cant

Comment: The Jacobian formula for transforming $(X,Y)\rightarrow (X,M)$ may be useful for evaluting $f_{X|M}(x|m)$ for $m \in (0,1)$ but is not useful when $m=1$ (since the answer is obvious here) or $m=0$ (since there are infinitely many ways for such a transformation to hold and the "sum" formula does not apply). But in general we have $P[M\leq m] = P[XY\leq m] = \int_{x=0}^1 P[xY\leq m]dx$. You would need to break the integral into two parts, compute both, then take derivative with respect to $m$ to compute $f_M(m)$ for $m \in (0,1)$.